# How to call a custom method within generic.view at the end of the request

Tags: python, django

I have a generic view in Django where I add a custom Mixin. I need the new mixin method `has_action` to be called at the end or towards the end of the view request cycle.

```
from django.views.generic import View

    class AboutView(MyCustomMix, View):
        #edited for brevity
```

Custom Mixin

```
def has_action(self, request, view):
     # do some stuff
```

What are my options here to make sure `has_action` is called? The only way I can think of is to  rename`has_action` method to something else like `def as_view` and use super as I know this gets called.

But is there a way I can get `has_action` to be called somewhere at the end of the request cycle within my view (I still need access to request, view). I've seen this could be done by overriding `init` on the view but but this gets run at the start of the request cycle.

Comment: `as_view` is not part of the request/response cycle, it is called when the urls are defined, so it would not be appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can override the [dispatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) method:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
   response = super(AboutView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
   self.has_action(request, self)
   return response
```

Not sure what the `view` parameter to `has_action` is.